# "Create Account: account Address already in use" when creating a custom token

Tags: spl-token

```
spl-token create-token 5bciMkmLh96tVzBHVS5ybxYPZFjaXydKZpRnstdoj3Zq.json
```

When creating token:

```
5bciMkmLh96tVzBHVS5ybxYPZFjaXydKZpRnstdoj3Zq under program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
Error: Client(Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x0", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(0, Custom(0))), logs: Some(["Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]", "Create Account: account Address { address: 5bciMkmLh96tVzBHVS5ybxYPZFjaXydKZpRnstdoj3Zq, base: None } already in use", "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 failed: custom program error: 0x0"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(0), return_data: None }) }) })
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3):

the extra parameter is for custom mint address. Looks like you put your wallet address there. This will not work because the address is already in use. Just leave it empty to create a new token mint on a new address.
So just:

```
spl-token create-token
```

You can not use your wallet address as an address for a token mint you can however grind yourself a vanity key pair like this:

```
solana-keygen grind --starts-with dog:1
```

and use that one as address for your token.

Comment: How can we create spl token which have same name of my wallet address? ‘spl-token create-token <key-pair file>

Comment: You can not do that you can grind yourself a nice address though. I updated the answer